# How can I send massive mail in java?

Tags: java, email

I have made a site where the users can subscribe to a workshop.

I want the teacher of each workshop to be able to send a mail to all his students (app 30 to 100 mail) , and sometimes I want to send a global mail to all the students (app 1000 to 3000 mail).

Now I use the library javamail with gmail, but I can't send a massive email (sending one email with many email address in bcc, app 3000 mail).

Is there a easy way to make an SMTP server in Java? And how can I make my emails avoid the spam folder?

Comment: You not only have to avoid the spam folder, you also have to avoid being blacklisted.  Be sure you research that and find out the recommendation from the major ISPs as well as hotmail, gmail, etc and ensure you're following all the guidelines set forth in the CAN/SPAM act.  Even if you're not in the U.S. those guidelines will serve you well.  (And you can't control your recipients spam filtering settings.)

Comment: Please define 'massive' mail - lots of individual emails (iterating over a list of email addresses) and/or sending one email with many email addresses in the BCC field?

Comment: You can probably find a mailing list where you send it an email and it gets forward to everyone on the list. This would be easier to do and less likely to get blacklisted.

Comment: @Brendan Long: how can I create a mail list in java?

Comment: @Brian: sending one email with many email address in bcc, I think the other option is to slow for a lot of mail

Comment: I mean find a website where you can setup a mailing list, then your Java program only needs to send one email to the mailing list. You could also set it up so students could respond to the mailing list if you want to allow discussions (in my experience, this is very helpful).